# How can a user sync all document libraries in their team site to OneDrive?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, document-library, onedrive-for-business

I have a team of business users that are most comfortable accessing their SharePoint documents via the OneDrive client. Each time a new person starts in their team they will open every single document library in the site and sync it to OneDrive - a very time intensive process that shouldn't be necessary.

Is there a way a user can sync a whole site or is there a way I can do this using a logon script for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map a drive to the SharePoint site, then the entirety of the site becomes available in Windows Explorer in a single connection. You also then don't have the entirety of your SharePoint site eating up local hard drive space. You also don't have the file limit restrictions (and selective sync until the new client is released).

I am in a similar situation in that everyone loves to work from mapped drives and now OneDrive that we're in O365. Doing it this way you lose out on so much functionality, it really annoys me that they want to work in archaic folder structures for file management, but live in the browser for everything else.

Comment: I didn't think this was possible - each time I try to map the drive I get an access denied error. My SharePoint main collection is in the trusted sites list - do I need to add every subsite into here that I want to map as well?

Comment: So I assumed from the error contents previously that it wasn't possible to map o365 to a drive... pleasantly surprised! Googling this now and making it happen. I'll leave this for a few more days as I did bounty it seeking a OneDrive solution but will set a reminder to award this to you if nothing else comes up in the next few days.

Comment: I believe there is a third party tool that helps persist the mapped drives, I don't have any experience with it, but it helps keep the connection active otherwise they will have a tendency to drop/disconnect at times.

Comment: It's worth noting that a mapped drive won't allow the users to access the files offline. This may not be an issue in your scenario, but ti is normally one of the main reasons users sync libraries like that.

Comment: True, although in my experience, offline access is in the overwhelming minority. Users want the mapped drive experience. Between syncing down your OneDrive for Business (1TB capacity, soon to be unlimited) and many document libraries, you are going to chew through your hard drive space.